# hadoop (HDFS) with diskless compute nodes

Tags: hadoop, share, hdfs

I have a small cluster with one node that has RAID storage, and several powerful diskless compute nodes that boot over PXE. All nodes are connected by InfiniBand (and 1G Ethernet for booting).

I need to deploy Hadoop on this cluster.

Please suggest optimal configuration
As I understand default configuration means that all compute nodes has self small storage, but in my situation (if I have NFS share) it will make too many copies by network. I have found resources about using Hadoop with Lustre, but I do not understand how to configure it

Comment: Why do you want to do it this way? I'd recommend a proper cluster with appropriate hardware and configurations.

Comment: All compute nodes should have large storage - that's where HDFS data lives. If you don't have lots of data then Hadoop is probably the wrong tool.

Comment: But why compute nodes can't get some portion (~10-15Gb, if it can be stored in RAM) of currently needed data from central storage? May be I just need to create virtual disk in memory for HDFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is probably possible but - instead of making use of Hadoop features - you are trying to find a way around them.

1. *Moving computation is cheaper than moving data* - **data locality** is one of the cornerstones of Hadoop and that's why all the worker nodes in the cluster are also storage nodes. Hadoop attempts to do as much computation as possible on the nodes where the processed blocks are located to avoid network congestion.

   https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module1.html

   > The Hadoop framework then schedules these processes in proximity to the location of data/records using knowledge from the distributed file system. Since files are spread across the distributed file system as chunks, each compute process running on a node operates on a subset of the data. Which data operated on by a node is chosen based on its locality to the node: most data is read from the local disk straight into the CPU, alleviating strain on network bandwidth and preventing unnecessary network transfers. This strategy of moving computation to the data, instead of moving the data to the computation allows Hadoop to achieve high data locality which in turn results in high performance.
2. MapReduce tends to generate large volumes of temporary files, so 15 GB per node is simply not enough storage.

Comment: Thank you. As i understand, after some research, the best solution in my (and can be in most other) situation is to use Apache Spark, which shows best performance, also use in-memory operations